# Print the output value of an array in twig [OctoberCMS]

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, twig, octobercms

I have an array of values in my component and I want to output it in the default.htm my component is like this:

```
  $settings = Settings::instance();
  $this->ogFbAdmins = $settings->str_og_fb_admins;
```

The ogFbAdmins is getting the values from an repeater field at the backend that field allows the user to create as many input boxes as he wants, I want to do something like a for each in php but on twig, if I output my array using this code:

```
foreach ($this->ogFbAdmins as $adm) {
              echo $adm['str_og_fb_admins'];
            }
```

it returns this:

```
admin1admin2
```

my twig code at my default.htm is like this:

```
{% if __SELF__.ogFbAdmins == true %}
{% for ad in __SELF__.ogFbAdmins %}
{% if ad|length %}
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="{{ ad }}" />
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

My this twig code returns an error

"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Array to string conversion")."

In the end what I want it to return is this:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin1" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin2" />
```

Feel free to ask anything if you don't understand the question.

Comment: You need to write a twig {% for %} loop ... see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change `content="{{ad}}"` to `content="{{ad.str_og_fb_admins}}"` it will make it work.

the twig code will be like this:

```
{% if __SELF__.ogFbAdmins == true %}
{% for ad in __SELF__.ogFbAdmins %}
{% if ad.str_og_fb_admins|length %}
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="{{ ad.str_og_fb_admins }}" />
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```